# Mock not behaving as expected when setup

Tags: c#, moq, autofac, xunit

I am trying to test a method with the name `GetAll` in a xUnit-Project of the class `AuhtorRepository`.

```
public class AuthorRepository : IAuthorRepository
{
    private readonly ISqlDb _db;
    public string Connection { get; set; }
    public AuthorRepository(ISqlDb db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<List<AuthorModel>> GetAll()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Author";
        List<AuthorModel> authors = await _db.LoadDataAsync<AuthorModel, dynamic>(sql, new { }, Connection);
        return authors; 
    }

}
```

In this method is the `LoadDataAsync` method used which I will mock in my test.

The structure of the interface looks like this.

```
public interface ISqlDb
{
    Task<List<T>> LoadDataAsync<T, U>(string sql, U parameters, string connection);
}
```

Finally the implementation of the test my xUnit-Project.

```
using Autofac.Extras.Moq;
using DataAccess.Library;
using Moq;
using Repository.Library.Models;
using Repository.Library.Repositories;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace RespositoryTests
{
    public partial class AuhtorRepositoryTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task GetAll_ShouldWorkd()
        {
            using (var autoMock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
            {
                //Arrange
                autoMock.Mock<ISqlDb>()
                    .Setup(x => x.LoadDataAsync<AuthorModel, dynamic>("SELECT * FROM Author", new { }, " "))
                    .ReturnsAsync(GetSamples());

                //Act
                var cls = autoMock.Create<AuthorRepository>();
                cls.Connection = " ";
                var expected = GetSamples();

                var acutal = await cls.GetAll();

                //Assert                
                Assert.Equal(expected.Count, acutal.Count);

            }

        }

        private List<AuthorModel> GetSamples()
        {
            var authors = new List<AuthorModel>();
            authors.Add(new AuthorModel { Id = 1, FirstName = "first name", LastName = "lastname" });
            authors.Add(new AuthorModel { Id = 3, FirstName = "Angela", LastName = "Merkel" });
            return authors;
        }
    }
}
```

The sturcture of the project looks like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4TPT.png

The test fails with the following statement:

> Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

So I expected the test should pass.

What I tried out so far:

-> I wrote a similar project with the same code, the only difference there is the project structure. Every interface and class was in the same Test-Project and the test passed.

Whereas in my `BookApp` Solution the `ISqlDb` is suited in the *DataAccess.Library* Project.

So it looks like that in the mocking the ReturnAsync method is not returning the values
from my GetSamples.

Please bear in mind that

- a) This is my first post on stackoverflow and
- b) I try to make my first steps in mocking ...

tried out:

```
 //Act
//var cls = autoMock.Create<AuthorRepository>();
//cls.Connection = "";
var cls = new AuthorRepository(autoMock.Create<ISqlDb>());
cls.Connection = "";
var expected = GetSamples();

var acutal = await cls.GetAll();

//Assert                
Assert.Equal(expected.Count, acutal.Count);
```

Comment: If you are writing test for AuthorRepository class then you need to create an object of that class. `var cls = autoMock.Create<AuthorRepository>();` is not needed... you need to do `var cls = new AuthorRepository(autoMock.Create<ISqlDb>();`

Comment: Thank you @Chetan for your quick response. Unfortunately the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

The mock is returning null by default because the invocation of the mocked member does not match what was setup. Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better under standing of how to use MOQ.

You need to use argument matchers here because the anonymous `new { }` used in setup wont match the reference of the one actually used when exercising  the test

```
//...

autoMock.Mock<ISqlDb>()
    .Setup(x => x.LoadDataAsync<AuthorModel, dynamic>("SELECT * FROM Author", It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(GetSamples());

//...
```

Note the use of `It.IsAny<object>()` to allow whatever you pass in to be allowed.

With the above change, the test passed as expected.

Comment: very well explained and it makes total sense. Yes, I definitely have a lot to learn in mocking. Thank you for sharing the moq quickstart.

Comment: @sonOfLiberty85 glad it helped. It this resolves your original problem then you can mark it as answered. Happy coding.